# PHP: ? and & in URLs - what's the difference?

Tags: php, url

what is the difference between ? and & in URLs?

e.g. `http://www.site.com/index.php?someVar=value&otherVar=value`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `?` marks the *beginning* of the query string, the `&` is used to separate individual variables *within* the query string.

So for instance, I'll modify your example to be a little more clear:

```
http://www.site.com/index.php?someVar=firstVal&otherVar=secondVal
```

The "location" part of the URL is everything up to but not including the `?`, so it would be simply:

```
http://www.site.com/index.php
```

This is what you're web server will use to find which script to execute. Then it will split off the query string (everything *after* the `?`) and pass that to your script (or more accurately, to PHP). The query string would be all of:

```
someVar=firstVal&otherVar=secondVal
```

PHP will then parse the query string, using the `&` as the delimiter between variables. So this query string would include two variables: `someVar` with value `firstVal`, and `otherVar` with value `secondVal`.

PHP will store the results of parsing the query string in the `$_GET` super global variable, which is just an associative array where the keys are the names of the parameters, and the values are of course the associated values.

So in PHP, if you do `var_dump($_GET)` with this example, it will look like this:

```
array(2) {
  ["someVar"]=>
  string(5) "firstVal"
  ["otherVar"]=>
  string(5) "secondVal"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`?` means "here come the parameters", so it's the first
`&` means "here comes another parameter", so it's for consecutive values

Comment: I like that, nicely put.